# How to equally fill padding between menu items to stretch menu width to 100% parent div width?

Tags: css, css-tables

What is the best no JS way (most commont browsers friendly) to achieve this?

I have found a few related questions & answers:

```
width: 100% / number_of_li-s_in_ul;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qx4WG/ ("static" calculated size for each li) - unable to use due different sizes of li

```
li {display: table-cell;}
```

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/jwJBd/1035/ -> works good, but I'm also using sub-menus and **position: relative;** doesn't work here to position the sub-menu below current li. When position is set to **static** it enlarges the parent LI every time it's set to display:block;

```
display: box;
```

never used it before, just read a few articles and it looks like the browser support is minimal

Comment: can you add a sub-menu to your jsfiddle ? I did this table-cell layout with sub-menu .. you will just have to position your subs relative to the trigering anchor, not the li itself.

Comment: Yes but how? The fiddle is updated..

Comment: did you try inline block plus text align justify? seems that this could help you

Comment: You mean inline-block on sub-menu? I need the sub-menu to display vertically..

Comment: i mean you can use text align justify in the root menu, then display inline block in the menu elements and if you want vertical submenu just use display block or inline block with 100% width

Comment: Text-align: justify on the root menu won't evenly place block elements to the full menu width: http://jsfiddle.net/jwJBd/1036/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to display evenly menu elements like a table would do AND be able to display css sub-menus using absolute and relative positioning.

Your jsfiddle was close, the only thing i had to fix was the positioning of the sub-menu

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    /*left: 0;*/ /* i removed this */
    position: absolute;
    /* PLAY with this */
}
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwJBd/1037/)

**[post edit]**

It would also be relevant to set your `<li>` parent with a `table-layout:fixed` property. This way, `<li>` will be set to equal width.

```
#horizontal-style {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed; /* try this */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem in my solution was, that I'm creating a Wordpress child theme and in the parent theme there was `left: -2px;` so I automatically set that to `left: 0;` and didn't bother to update to `left: auto;` which in the end helped..

Comment: It is also good to set `.nav-menu {table-layout: fixed;}`. This will compute and set the same size for each .nav-menu > li item.